# Using a DXF file to make a 3D map in QGIS

Tags: qgis, raster, vector, dxf, 3d-map

This might be a long shot but I'm trying to make 3D map to render from a DXF file in QGIS (3.14). The options I get when I press (View>New 3D map view>configure>terrain) is following: Flat terrain, DEM (raster layer), online and mesh.

The only one that can render for me is flat terrain. I suspect that I need to convert my DXF file to DEM but DEM is raster based while my DXF file seems to be vector based?

I tried to to use the vector to raster tool (Raster>Conversion>Rasterize(vector to raster)) and then to use that file to make a 3D file. The challenge is that my newly created raster file is invisible and I can't see it. Is there some other way or am I doing something wrong?

If I use the QGis2threejs plugin I get the following export:
[image: 1]
It is a model of a quarry

Comment: Please [Edit] the Question to clarify the dimensionality of your DXF file. If it's not 3D, then you can't use it in isolation to make a 3D map, and you can't use it to make a DEM, either. DTED level 1 data is available for most of the Earth (everywhere SRTM was able to reach). You seem to be trying to push on the short end of the lever.

Comment: What's the content of the DXF file? It's it actually a dem, or is it structures like buildings?

Comment: Thank you for taking your time. To respond your question Vince Im quite sure it is 3D. If I use the QGis2threejs plugin I get the following export as you can see in the imgur link. https://imgur.com/rA668J1. ndawson its a model of a quarry